# Asp.Net Modal Pop-Up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modalpopupextender, modalpopups

I am working on this ASP.Net where I have to implement a modal pop-up, and I am hesitating on how to achieve this. I have various solutions in mind, but I don't find them elegant enough.

First, I have been hesitating between using ASp.Net ModalPopupExtender and using jQuery to display the modal pop-up. I prefer jQuery, but I am afraid of incompatibilities. On the other hand, when I used Modal Popup Extenders in the past, I found the code a bit convoluted. Microsoft's stuff works well when doing things as they think you should do them, but most of the time, the requirements I get are for scenarios that are different for which Microsoft's controls do not work out of the box.

Second, I am hesitating between loading partial html and using an iFrame in the modal pop-up. I would prefer to avoid using an iFrame, since it is a bit more complicated then to control the modal pop-up and doing things like closing the modal pop-up by pressing on a button within the iFrame (I know ways of doing it, but I find them a bit awkward). However, I don't know how to present a sequence of pages of content within the modal pop-up, as shown in the example below, without using an iFrame. Can it be done?

First, there is a main page with a link to open de Modal Pop-Up:
[image: Main Page]
In the initial Modal Pop-Up, some information is displayed and it is possible to close de pop-up or to start some processing:
[image: Modal Pop-Up 1]
Then a Please Wait message is displayed in the modal pop-up during the processing:
[image: Modal Pop-Up 2]
Once the processing is done, a summary of the result is displayed in the pop-up. At this point, it is possible to either click on a link to see more details or to click on a button to close the modal pop-up:
[image: Modal Pop-Up 3]
If the user clicks on a link to see details, these are displayed in the modal pop-up. The pop-up has to be resized:
[image: Modal Pop-Up 4]

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://collegegfx.com/10-best-jquery-popup-plugins/) are some jquery popup plugins that you may use.

Comment: I know how to open a jQuery modal pop-up. My problem is more about how to update only the part of the page inside the modal pop-up. Let's say I have a form in the modal pop-up, and that submitting the form does not simply close de modal, but it displays some results with the option to close de modal or to click on links to see more info within the modal. Also, I would like validation to work properly on the form.

Comment: apply same pop-up css to all the forms that you need and show/hide them according your needs. i have done this in one of my projects.

Comment: Did you use full page updates, partial page update using UpdatePanels, or iFrames where to load the content of your modal pop-ups?

Comment: you can do what ever you require, i placed number of divs in same page and swapped their visibility using jquery. I used partial page update. No iFrames involved. No update panels required either because jquery is doing everything.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an iFrame, but I believe Ankit's solution would work too. One has to weigh the pros and cons of each solution for their specific project to choose the proper solution.